# I am trying to fetch orders for last "N" months. In the following query I need to dynamically set the value for months

Tags: mysql, spring, hsqldb, dao, spring-jdbc

I am getting java exception while setting the value for months :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM {Order} 
 WHERE creationtime >= NOW() 
   AND creationtime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),  INTERVAL ?months MONTH)
```

However this query is working properly in mysql.

expection trace :

ERROR [hybrisHTTP34] [FlexibleSearch] Flexible search error occured...
May 08, 2017 1:53:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/jafrastorefront] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.exceptions.FlexibleSearchException: SQL search error - enable the property 'flexible.search.exception.show.query.details' for more details] with root cause
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: ?

Comment: What java exception? Elaboration like this does make no sense.

Comment: what are yiu suing ? PreparedStatement or hibernate? in first case it should be just `?`, in latter - it should be `?` or `:months`

Comment: Your query condition is wrong. It has creationtime >= NOW() which means the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about java exception, but logic wise, you code has this problem.

If `NOW()` is `5th May`, `DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` will be `5th April`, So you are selecting records `> 5th May` and `< 5th April` at the same time. Hence you will get no results.

Use between to avoid confusion, use `BETWEEN`.

```
SELECT * FROM {Order} 
WHERE creationtime BETWEEN
   DATE_SUB(NOW(),  INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
AND   
   NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data for last 'N' months , you may use the following query directly .

```
where creationtime>= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 month)
```

in java following should work.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM {Order} 
 WHERE creationtime>= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL ? month)
```

Answer (score 0):

The HSQLDB SQL syntax is

```
SELECT * FROM "Order"
WHERE creationtime >= NOW() - CAST(? AS INTERVAL MONTH)
```